# Black window when moving Direct3D11 window from screen edge

Tags: directx, directx-11

When a Direct3D11 window is moved below taskbar and then I click to a window caption and move this window back to a screen center, I frequently (not always) observe a black window instead of my content.

I use DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL and BufferCount = 2

I use smart optimization for rendering - I know that I work with 2 flipping buffers in a sequence. And I render/update only necessary parts of my window. I show still images.

It seems that after moving a window outside screen edges, my backbuffers getting cleared sometimes and I don't know why it happens. A size of a window didn't change.

Comment: It very depends on your code, obviously. Difficult to say w/o any piece of it:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regrettably we cannot create an example, as we use Freepascal code.